# Error importing cloudinary in React to upload images

Tags: reactjs, import, cloudinary

I'm using react and when importing cloudinary to upload images, I get this error:

Console

```
cloudinary.js:1 
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/cloudinary/cloudinary.js (cloudinary.js:1:1)
    at Object.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at Module../src/helpers/fileUpload.js (firebase-config.js:22:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at Module../src/actions/notes.js (auth.js:85:1)
    at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

screen

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/cloudinary/lib-es5/api_client/execute_request.js 5:52-67

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\-\-\-\-\proyect\node_modules\cloudinary\lib-es5\api_client'
```

This is my code:

```
import 'setimmediate';
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary'

cloudinary.config({ 
    cloud_name: 'name', 
    api_key: 'key', 
    api_secret: 'secret',
  });


export const fileUpload = (file, idNote) => {
    
    cloudinary.v2.api.update_resources_access_mode(file, {
        public_id: idNote,
        folder: 'app',
        invalidate: true
    }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        }
        return {a: result.secure_url, b: result.public_id};
    });
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "proyect",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "cloudinary-core": "^2.12.3",
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.8",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cloudinary": "^1.29.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.2",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "^0.6.5",
    "react-error-overlay": "^6.0.9"
  }
}
```

The error happens when importing.
I already looked for information in other places, but I can't find the solution.

In the tests section I already imported it and it worked for me, but in the file that I have the main code it doesn't work for me.

How do I solve it?

Comment: The [Cloudinary Node.js SDK](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/backend_sdks) is a backend implementation and you will need to POST your assets from your frontend. Alternatively, you could use the [React SDK](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/frontend_sdks). You can check the [sample project using the React SDK here](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-react).

Answer (score 0):

To use version 2 of Cloudinary's SDK this is how you first import cloudinary into your application.

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
```

From the error above I can see the message `process is not defined`. If you have stored your environment variables in a .env file this is how you reference the variables in your application

```
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.YOUR_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.YOUR_CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.YOUR_CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
  secure: true,
});
```

Comment: I already did it and it still gives me that error.